# java logic for moving ball in automode in square shape i am implementing simple logic

Tags: java, logic

```
//code to move ball down direction y axis
void move()
{
    if (y+150<760)
    {
        y=y+1;
    } 
//code to move ball at x axis
else if (x+1<1000)
{
    x=x+1;

}
//  code move ball up direction *here the problem exists need help in logic what should i edit down in this code to move the ball up direction.
else if(y<160)
    {
        y=y-1;

    }
```

the third comment shows the error actually I need to look that the ball move in the up direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its due to your first if statements. For the first statement to fail y has to be greater than or equal to 760. This means when you get to the 3rd if statement y will be equal to 760 which means y<160 is false. You need to add lower limit to the first if statement something like this.

```
void move()
{
    if (y+150<760 && y >160)
    {
        y=y+1;
    } 
}
```

**Edit**
Just to note, this is fix the logic problem but you are still going to have issues. Just look at this scenario. I know you have X's as well but just working with the Y's. 
Pass one y = 609 the first if is true `y = y + 1 = 610`
Pass two y = 610 the first if is false `y = y - 1 = 609`
Pass three y = 609 the first if is true `y = y + 1 = 610`
pass four y = 610 the first if is false `y = y - 1 = 609`

**Update** 
**How does the logic work for moving a ball in a square pattern.** 
You have your x and y points. so lets say the square has coordinates of top left (0, 50), top Right (50, 50),  bottom right (50, 0), bottom left (0,0)

You want to set X and Y at the start to default point (0,0)(or any of the 4 points), then you keep increasing Y until 50, this is up direction. So that is `if(x==0 && y<=50) y=y+1` then you move on to moving to the next point `if(x<=50 && y == 50) x = x + 1` and you keep going on with that logic

Comment: well I tried what you told but i think its getting more come , could you look at my whole code its urgent .

Comment: You want to automate the ball to go in a square. I will update the answer and explain.

Comment: I got the logic you told but again I am stuck with the up direction , I am writing if(x<=50 && y==0) y=y+1 . what should I use for up direction.   @Jonathan.Hickey      UPDATED THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR EVERY THING I GOT THE ANSWER . ITS WORKING HURREYYYYYYY..... THANK YOU.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help